# SmartWatch startVibrator in DIM state

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I call `startVibrator(0200, 0000, 1);` in my callback in a `ControlExtension`.
It works when the `SmartWatch` is not dimmed, once the `SmartWatch` is dimmed, it
does not vibrate. Is this normal? And how can I get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the Screen state On and it will vibrate. It depends on what you want to achieve by vibration, either it is a notification vibration or just using it for some other form of game/user interaction.This is the usual behavior though.

Comment: When I get a GPS fix I want to vibrate to notify the user there is a fix (also when dimmed). I think it should vibrate in dimmed state. Adding a Notification, one also get a Notification message (also need a GUI interaction). How can I send a Notification and only vibrate (without message)? And can I control the default xml preference settings for a Notification configuration?

Comment: Ended up leaving the screen ON until GPS fix then vibrate and finally DIM it. Not the perfect solution since I also want to vibrate in dimmed state later.